# Restricting Specific CAS Protected Resources By LDAP Group Membership

Tags: python, authentication, drupal, cas, django-authentication

I've recently been tasked with implementing a new CAS server and I decided to go with django-mama-cas for being "lightweight" and written in python. I've set it up and managed to integrate with our LDAP using django-auth-ldap. Works great, I can use SSO login/logout just fine. We also use drupal with phpCAS client module for CAS authentication and currently allow any LDAP user to access CAS protected resources.

My problem is this:

We want to be able to restrict certain webpages/apps/assets to specific LDAP groups. I know I can do this with apache modules mod_authz_dbm or mod_authz_groupfiles and .htaccess files. I'm assuming there are other ways to go about this, and if so, what are they? Can I write custom views that utilize django-auth-ldap/django's group mirroring? Or am I totally out of my element here? Please help guide me.